# Why my request doesn't transform json to model object in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

i want to test my register controller and i'm getting and error bcz posted data doesn,t tranform to my model and test fall on validation.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/register", consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    private String postRegistration( @ModelAttribute @Valid final  UserCreateFormDto user, final BindingResult result,
                                    final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, final WebRequest webRequest) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.user", result);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("user", user);
            return "redirect:/register";
        }
        if (userService.checkEmailExist(user.getEmail())) {
            return "redirect:/register?exist";
        }
        final User registered = userService.createNewUserAccount(user);

        try {
            final String appUrl = webRequest.getContextPath();
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(new RegistrationCompleteEvent(registered, webRequest.getLocale(), appUrl));
            return "redirect:/login?success";
        } catch (UserNotExistsException e) {
            return "redirect:/register";
        }
    }
```

and test

```
@Test
    public void shouldReturnHttp201WhenUserIsCreated() throws Exception {
        //given
        final UserCreateFormDto userCreateFormDto = createUserCreateForm();
        final User user = createUser();

        given(userService.checkEmailExist(userCreateFormDto.getEmail())).willReturn(false);
        given(userService.createNewUserAccount(any(UserCreateFormDto.class))).willReturn(user);

        //when
        final MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc
                .perform(post("/register").with(csrf())
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userCreateFormDto)))
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse();

        //then
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.CREATED.value());
        assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(userJacksonTester.write(user).getJson());
        verify(userService).createNewUserAccount(refEq(userCreateFormDto));
    }
```

[I think this photo should explain as easy as it can](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGqZY.png)

Edit
I tried to mock BindingResult but after reading more it wasn't a good idea.

Comment: Do you want to bind form input fields or a JSON body. Your test is for the latter while your controller is for the former. If you want to consume a body and not a form use `@RequestBody` instead of `@ModelAttribute`.

Comment: I want to bind form data. I'm using thymeleaf to post data. So my question is how to bind input fields to my object?

Comment: Then don't use `content` but rather add parameters to your request to use for binding. Just as a form would do.

Comment: It works! Thank you, my friend. You helped me a lot!